What are the best practices when working with the Atomic Design methodology in Flutter?
I’m starting to explore Atomic Design for building UIs in Flutter and have a few questions to help me understand it better:
Templates in Atomic Design: I get the basics of atoms, molecules, and organisms, but I'm a bit confused about templates. What exactly are they for, and how do they fit into a Flutter project using Atomic Design?
API Integration and Atomic Design: where should API calls be made, and what is the recommended implementation for tasks such as pagination?? What are the best practices for fetching and displaying data while keeping components reusable?
Naming Conventions and Atomic Design: I’m concerned about naming conflicts when breaking down UIs into smaller components. How can I ensure clear and consistent naming across atoms, molecules, organisms, and templates in a Flutter project?
I appreciate any insights you can share.
